# How to add integer and date query in ms access from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to add a number and date in the ms-access database table using vb.net. First, here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

    Public query As String


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
        
            'Variable Declaration        

            Dim pn As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            Dim dayadd As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value


            'Is index 0 or 1?

            If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                dayadd = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(15)
            Else
                dayadd = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(7)
            End If

            'MS-Access SQL Queries          

            Dim dbcon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectS)
            dbcon.Open()
            query = "INSERT INTO Swab (PatientNo, NextSwab) VALUES (@pn, @dayadd)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, dbcon)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", pn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dayadd", dayadd)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

What i'm trying to do is when a user selected a ComboBox and returned an index it will update the days from the date that they picked on the DateTimePicker. I used `AddDays()` Function with it so that i can update the days on it which will return either 15 days or 7. and then use the updated date to transfer in the MS database along with the `PatientNo` which is variable `pn`. But for some reason i kept getting an error on the SQL part. It stops at the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` Code, i used the `Try Catch` to try to read the error and it shows me this:

[image]

I'm a beginner in both Vb.net and MS-Access SQL.

Comment: What does .AddDays() return. Maybe, that's your error.

Comment: Show the design of your access table

Comment: @DaedraEYE, that is the `DateTime.AddDays` method so it returns a `DateTime`. It wouldn't matter anyway because `dayadd` is type `DateTime` so whatever that method returns would have to either be that type or be implicitly converted to that type or that assignment would throw an exception.

Comment: There's not much point setting the `dayadd` variable on the line that declares it if you're then going to set it to a different value in that `If...Else` block. You could actually replace those six lines of code with this one: `Dim dayadd = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(If(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0, 15, 7))`.

Comment: You really ought to work on your naming too. NEVER accept the default names for controls and ALWAYS use names that represent the purpose. You should change `TextBox1` and `DateTimePicker` to `patientNoTextBox` and `nextSwabDateTimePicker` respectively. I'd also suggest changing `pn` and `dayadd` to `patientNo` and `nextSwab`. I'd go further and use `NextSwabDate` in the database and `nextSwabDate` in VB too. Just make the small effort it takes to be clear. If you don't, trust me, you will end up coming back to old code and having no idea what you were thinking.

Comment: Finally, I'm guessing that you only want to store the date and not the time in this particular instance. In that case, unless you have already zeroed the time portion in your `DateTimePicker`, you ought to use `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date`, which will return another `DateTime` with the same date and the time zeroed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney actually i forgot to mention this is a test code that i have to implement in my final project, actually your right about the naming stuff it's a bad habit of mine to name variables incompetently when testing stuff. i apologize for late reply too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, but *AddWithValue* may fool you. Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dayadd", DbType.DateTime).Value = dayadd;
```

Source: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The OP is using `OleDb` rather than `SqlClient` so, while the principle is sound, the implementation is not correct. Also, there are fewer options for date types in Access than SQL Server so it's actually less likely to be that problem. That certainly doesn't mean that your advice is not sound, but it may not actually be the solution to this specific problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Right. Here, I think it should be `DbType` - as edited.

Comment: It ought to be `OleDbType.Date`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: That may vary well be so. I can't tell for sure, as I always use the _DataTableAdapters_ to not worry about these details.

Comment: thank you so much. i used the `OleDbType.DBDate` to output the date, i don't know why the `AddWithValue` doesn't work tho, Does it not work in ms-access ?

Comment: The article link I posted lists some of the reasons. It is not related to Microsoft Access specifically.